# Как при выборе даты вызвать код на PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, дата

Есть поле `type="date"` - календарь; и есть код на PHP, который нужно выполнить при выборе даты при помощи `Ajax` запроса. Как при выборе даты вызвать этот код? Я только начинаю писать и Ajax я не знаю, но если есть хороший пример, напишите, буду разбираться.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#CallTime').on('change',function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'index.php',
            data: 'CallTime='+$(this).val(),
            success: function(data){

            }
        });

    });

});
</script>

    <?php
    if (!empty($_POST['CallTime']))
        {
            $t = '<select name="time">';
            $t .= '<option value="">1</option>';
            $t .= '</select>';
            echo $t;
        }
    ?>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <p>Выберите дату:</p>   
        <input type="date" name="CallTime" id="CallTime">
        <input type="submit" value="Ок">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($obj['Intervals'][$b] as $a)
{
    if ($a['State'] == 0)
    {
        $t .= '<option value="'.$a['StartTime'].'">'.$a['StartTime'].'</option>';
    }
}
echo $t;
```

Comment: а вот этот файл с расширением `.php` или `.html`?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan .php

Comment: А понял, у вас строка `$('#CallTime')` означает выбор элемента с `id="CallTime"`, А вы написали так `<input type="date" name="CallTime">` - А должно быть вот так - `<input type="date" name="CallTime" id="CallTime">`.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan добавила id="CallTime", но это не помогло.

Comment: После этой строки `$('#CallTime').on('change',function(){` напишите хоть `alert('что нибуть')`, посмотрим работает ли `onchange`, Оно должно работать тогда когда меняется там дата

Comment: Ну как получилось?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan сообщение появляется "подтвердите действие..."

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59598/discussion-between-razmik-galstyan-and-).

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan подскажите плиз из-за чего не работает в цикле? я вывожу значения объектов из json-строки в выпадающий список. код я добавила в вопрос.

Comment: сейчас посмотрю

Comment: надо ошибку скинуть если есть, если нет сделайте в success `console.log(data)` и  посмотрим что там вывело

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan всё, работает, сама запуталась)

Comment: Значит могу и подождать с моими ответами))))

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan ajax не выполняется, как только я в строку запроса добавляю $usl. Строка запроса $data = 'command=cmd&usluga='.$usl.'&DateFrom=31.05.2017'; Не знаете почему так происходит?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59612/discussion-between-razmik-galstyan-and-nataka).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот пример по которой можете реализовать задуманное вами:

Допустим у вас в коде где то написано ваш `input`:

```
<input type="date" name="CallTime" id="CallTime" />
<select name="time" id="times_option"><option>select</option></select>
```

Если вам нужно что бы ваш код работал после выбора даты то сначала нужно перехватить событие `onchage` вашего `input`-а, А патом сделать `Ajax` запрос на сервер, передавав нужные данные.

Все это сделаем при помощи `jQuery`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#CallTime').on('change',function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'response.php',
            data: 'CallTime='+$(this).val(),
            success: function(data){
                $('#times_option').append(data);
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Поля `ajax` запроса обозначают следующее:

```
type - тип запроса
url - адрес по которой должен идти запрос
data - параметры запроса
success - функция где возвратиться правильный ответ нашего запроса
```

Теперь давайте рассмотрим серверную часть запроса который в нашем случае будет в файле `response.php`:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['CallTime']))
    {
        $t = '<option value="">1</option>';
        echo $t;
    }
?>
```

Поскольку мы сделали `post` запрос, в сервере наши переменные будут в суперглобальном `$_POST` массиве `php`;

И после манипуляции с данными мы делаем возврат каких то данных в наш запрос.И это делаеться строкой `echo ответ нашего ajax запроса;`

Comment: А код jQuery должен быть в отдельном файле?

Comment: @Наталия вообще то правильно сделать в отдельном файле и прикрепить его там где вам нужно, но если и будет в файле где ваш код `html` то работать будет.

Comment: Добавила в тег <head> строку <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>, а в тег <body> добавила код jQuery в <script>. Дальше я не понимаю. Мне нужно, чтобы после выбора даты у меня отобразился выпадающий список, код нужно прописывать в <?php ?> или success: function(data){}. Если я прописываю в <?php ?> и выбираю дату - ничего не происходит.

Comment: @Наталия измените вопрос и скиньте скрины я посмотрю, так толком не понял что вы сделали

Comment: Добавила свой код в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Вот простой рабочий вариант, на стороне php к примеру в файле `date.php` получаете значение даты через `$_POST['date']` и делаете с ней что вам надо.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.date-picker', function(event) {
 console.log('Выбрана дата:' + $(this).val());
 // Отправляем запрос
 $.ajax({
  url: '/date.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {date: $(this).val()},
 })
 .done(function(response) {
  console.log("Всё хорошо, сервер вернул ответ");
 })
 .fail(function() {
  console.log("Что-то на сервере не так");
    
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" class="date-picker">
```